# Why truncatechars won't works properly?

Tags: django

`{{ noticia.imagem_chamada }}` returns `"abc.jpg"`.

`{{ noticia.imagem_chamada|truncatechars:4 }}` returns nothing!

Why?

Comment: Is it `imagem` or `image`?

Comment: Is imagem. My code is correct (
I just wrote it wrong here). I just checked it right now.
CTRL+C CTRL+V of my code is:
{{ noticia.imagem_chamada|truncatechars:4 }} 
this return nothing
but
{{ noticia.imagem_chamada }}
returns abc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `trucantechars` should be `truncatechars`

Comment: Sorry... I was make a mistake to post this question... I'm really write correct truncatechars in my code and the returns is nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You make a typo.

For example:

```
{{ value|truncatechars:7 }}
```

If value is **"Joel is a slug"**, the output will be **"Joel i…"**.

For more [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

Comment: Yeah! This code works fine. But in my case, {{ noticia.image_chamada|trucantechars:4  }} returns nothing and I really don't understand...

Comment: Add `TEMPLATES ` from `settings.py` in you question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice filter:

```
{{ noticia.imagem_chamada|slice:":-4" }}
```

[You can check more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

Comment: I solved otherwise:
@register.filter
def cut(value, arg):
    """Removes all values of arg from the given string"""
    return value.replace(arg, '')